# How do I set working directory for R scripts in Snakemake?

Tags: r, snakemake, working-directory

I have used the following recommendations as a guide for building the directory structure.

https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html

If I have an R script (e.g. script2.R) which is located in workflow/scripts/script2.R, how can I tell Snakemake that the working directory is located above "workflow/"?

Example:
My_project/workflow/scripts/script2.R

Here "My_project" is to be announced as the working directory without hardcoding.
In other words, R is supposed to take "My_project" as the working directory.

I run "snakemake --profile slurm" from "My_project" dir.

How do I have to do this? Can I define this in "config.yaml"?
Or do I have to specify this in the respective "rule"?

My rule looks like this:

```r
rule seurat:
    input:
        tsv="results/souporcell_{sample}/clusters.tsv",
        mtx="results/cr_{sample}/outs/filtered_feature_bc_matrix"
    output:
        rds_export = "results/seurat_{sample}.rds"
    log: "results/seurat_{sample}.log"
    params: 
        k_indiv=config["INDIVIDUALS"],
        sample = "{sample}"
    #conda:
        #"envs/r_software.yaml"
    script: "workflow/scripts/seurat.R"
```

My R-script looks like:

```r
sample <- snakemake@params[['sample']]

input <- read_delim(here::here(paste0("My_project/results/souporcell_", 
                    sample,"/clusters.tsv")),
                    delim = "\t", escape_double = FALSE, 
                    trim_ws = TRUE)

k_indiv <- snakemake@params[['k_indiv']]
no_clusters <- (1:k_indiv)

# Read MTX/TSV files (results in an S4 object)
counts.data <- Read10X(
  data.dir = here::here(paste0("My_project/results/cr_", sample, 
                        "/outs/filtered_feature_bc_matrix")),
  gene.column = 2, 
  cell.column = 1, 
  unique.features = TRUE, 
  strip.suffix = FALSE
)

seurat_object <- CreateSeuratObject(counts.data, project = sample)
seurat_object <- AddMetaData(object = seurat_object, metadata = 
                             input$assignment, col.name = "assignment")

# Remove "NA" (doublets cells / two or more cells in one GEM)
seurat_filtered <- subset(seurat_object, subset = assignment != "NA")

# Split S4 object by condition
seurat_split.list <- SplitObject(seurat_filtered, split.by = "assignment")

# Export the S4 object
saveRDS(seurat_split.list, file = here::here(paste0(
                           "My_project/results/seurat_", sample,".rds")))

# Save image for debugging
save.image("snake_debug.RData")
```

I would be grateful for any advice!

I have tried to adjust the paths.
Running the script from the command line via Rscript.
It worked via the command line alone.
It is definitely a problem with the working directory.

With the tips in
https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#r-and-r-markdown

because no workspace was saved via save.image(), which I could have examined.

**My expectation is that when using external scripts, the root directory from where I call "snakemake" will be used as the working directory.**

Comment: What problems are you encountering with your current setup? Snakemake usually does consider the directory from where it is called the `cwd`, see [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#configure-working-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I have moved the snake file to the directory above. Now it works.